# AngularJS2 cancel parent element action?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<div (click)="parentAction()"> 
    <div (click)="childAction()"></div>
</div>
```

I want to trigger `childAction` only here but both `parentAction` and `childAction` is getting executed. How can I stop `parentAction` in this?

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-event-propagation-in-angular-2

Comment: Didn't know the right keyword for it. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div (click)="parentAction()"> 
    <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation();childAction()"></div>
</div>
```