# How to disable the div tag in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to disable the div tag after a success callback of that action.

please look my ion-content

```
<ion-content padding class="forgot-password">
  <div [ngClass]="{active: isOn,disabled: isDisabled}">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Email/Mobile</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="loginId"></ion-input>
    </ion-item> <br><br>

    <button class="float-right" (click)="generateOTP(!isOn);">Send OTP</button><br><br><br>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div *ngIf="showRePasswd">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Enter OTP</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="passwd"></ion-input>
    </ion-item> <br><br>

    <button class="float-right" (click)="resetPassword();">Send Password</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

here is my .ts file

```
export class ForgotPasswordPage {

    public loginId = "";
    public passwd = "";

  public showRePasswd = false;
  isDisabled = false;
  isOn = false;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private logger: Logger, private user: Users) {

  }

  generateOTP(newstate) {
    this.logger.info("invoking generateOTP FN");
    var _this = this;
    this.user.generateOTP(this.loginId, function(result,data){
      if(result == '1') {
        alert(data);
        _this.showRePasswd = !_this.showRePasswd;
        _this.isDisabled = true;
        _this.isOn = newstate;
      }
      else {
        //this.showRePasswd = this.showRePasswd;
        alert(data);
      }
    })
  }

  resetPassword() {
    this.logger.info("invoking resetPassword FN");
    var _this = this;

    this.user.resetPassword(this.passwd, function(result,data) {
      if(result == '1') {
        alert(data);
        _this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
      }
      else {
        alert(data);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

> I tried `[ngClass]` but i am not able to make my div tag disable after the success callback.

I also tried using `[disabled]` but not working

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/a4YdtmWywhJ33uqfpPPn?p=preview) for disable a div tag but in my case not working

> My requirement is to make my input field and button to be disabled after success callback

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can add the attribute like

```ts
<div [attr.disabled]="isDisabled ? true : null">
```

but `<div>` doesn't support the `disabled` attribute.

Perhaps this is what you want

```ts
<div (click)="isDisabled ? $event.stopPropagation() : myClickHandler($event); isDisabled ? false : null"
   [class.isDisabled]="isDisabled"></div>
```

with some custom CSS that makes `.isDiabled` look disabled.

It might be better to create a method to put the code there instead of inline.

Comment: insted of using ngClass i tried your answer but still i was able to edit my input field in my div tag

Comment: `div` can't be disabled (HTML limitation, not an Angular2 limitation). You can set the `disabled` attribute and apply CSS to it or you set `disabled` on all child elements that actually can be disabled individually.

Comment: To add to what @MohanGopi said, (click) event of the div that has [attr.disabled] set is also generated. So we cannot disable the clicks of that div.

Comment: You can use `<div>(click)="$event.preventDefault();false"</div>`

Comment: Ok, Can we make it conditional also? like if not disabled , (click) calls a method, and if disabled, uses what you mentioned.

Comment: Right, also I changed `preventDefault` to `stopPropagation`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-event-propagation-in-angular-2/35274069#35274069

Comment: @ritesh I can't make any sense of your comment

Comment: [class.isDisabled] this does not works and gives a parser error.

Comment: @ritesh can you reproduce in a Plunker or at least provide the exact error message. There is nothing I can do with the information you provided. It's definitely valid Angular binding syntax.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : ritesh is correct, you have so many comments, you give valid comments, but you write perhaps that perhaps this, etc. etc. your html is also not valid, you close div 2 times ( <div>(click) ), write the correct answer in answer, not in comments (start with, this can't be done, you can simulate this way)

Comment: For those who need the CSS, its `pointer-events: none;`

Answer (score 12):

You can use CSS property **pointer-events: none;** in your tag div:

```
<ion-content padding class="forgot-password">
  <div style="pointer-events: none;">
   ...
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is used in my Angular 8 project:
First set to HTML file like below.
Set to Div tag ngClass=>

```
<div class="col-md-3" [ngClass]="{disabledNoOfCasesDiv: !isActiveNOofCasesNo}>
<label class="control-label mb-2">No. of Cases Receive</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="CollectJob.NoOfCases"
placeholder="No. Cases Receive" name="NoCasesReceive">
</div>
```

Then next step write CSS for disabling events:

```
.disabledNoOfCasesDiv{ pointer-events: none; opacity: 2.0;}
```

Then last:

declare the variable and set to boolean

```
 isActiveNOofCasesNo: boolean;
```

Then next just pass true/false values wherever you want to enable div tag or disable div tag, div will automatically enabled or disabled.

```
this.isActiveNOofCasesNo = true;
this.isActiveNOofCasesNo = false;
```

Thank You..... Happy Learning!...:) [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) [html](/questions/tagged/html) [css](/questions/tagged/css) [ionic](/questions/tagged/ionic) [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript)

Answer (score 1):

You Can easily enable/disable the DOM elements using the Angular Directives :-

Create a Simple Directive - **DisableDirective**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

const DISABLED = 'disabled';
const APP_DISABLED = 'app-disabled';
const TAB_INDEX = 'tabindex';
const TAG_ANCHOR = 'a';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDisable]'
})
export class DisableDirective implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() appDisable = true;

  constructor(private eleRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.disableElement(this.eleRef.nativeElement);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.disableElement(this.eleRef.nativeElement);
  }

  private disableElement(element: any) {
    if (this.appDisable) {
      if (!element.hasAttribute(DISABLED)) {
        this.renderer.setAttribute(element, APP_DISABLED, '');
        this.renderer.setAttribute(element, DISABLED, 'true');

        // disabling anchor tab keyboard event
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === TAG_ANCHOR) {
          this.renderer.setAttribute(element, TAB_INDEX, '-1');
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (element.hasAttribute(APP_DISABLED)) {
        if (element.getAttribute('disabled') !== '') {
          element.removeAttribute(DISABLED);
        }
        element.removeAttribute(APP_DISABLED);
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === TAG_ANCHOR) {
          element.removeAttribute(TAB_INDEX);
        }
      }
    }
    if (element.children) {
      for (let ele of element.children) {
        this.disableElement(ele);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now Use this directive with your component div :-

```
<div [appDisable]="true">
</div>
```

*Note - Not to forget register Directive in your AppModule.*

Please Refer the [POST](https://medium.com/@imdurgeshpal/enable-disable-all-dom-elements-inside-div-in-angular-using-directive-56ca4602ab7b) for the detailed discription.

Comment: It only works on pure divs. If the divs contains material element, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

in html

<div[appViewDisable]="disable_condition">

in .ts

disable_condition = True or False

True will disable the content init.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Div element cannot be disabled like form controls. You can disable form controls in div instead.

Provided example has custom class "disabled"

```
styles: [`
    .button {
      width: 120px;
      border: medium solid black;
    }

    .active {
      background-color: red;
    }

    .disabled {
      color: gray;
      border: medium solid gray;
    }
  `]
```

Comment: I really don't understand what u want to achieve. Can you provide a desired effect? [ngClass]="{active: isOn,disabled: isDisabled}">is in your template file.

Comment: @MohanGopi you can also build a custom container (directive) that will disable all children on demand.

Answer (score 0):

HTML file

```
div [ngClass]="condition"
```

ts file

```
this.condition = 'mydisable';
```

css file

```
.mydisable {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```