# Angular 2+ attr.disabled is not working for div when I try to iterate ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm working on a appointment booking app, where I'm displaying time slots for appointments using `*ngFor` to loop.

**html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of allTimeSlots">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-slot" [attr.disabled]="item.status" (click)="slotSelected($event)">
            <input type="radio" name="slot" value="{{item.timeSlot}}">
            <span class="icon">{{item.timeSlot}}</span> {{item.status}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**typescript**

```js
for (var index = 0; index < this.totalMinutes; index += 15, i++) {
  this.allTimeSlots[i] = new allTimeSlots("", false);

  this.allTimeSlots[i].timeSlot = (hour <= 12 ? hour : hour - 12) + ":" + (minute <= 9 ? ("0" + minute) : minute) + " " + ampm;
  this.bookedTimeSlots.forEach(element => {
    if (this.allTimeSlots[i].timeSlot == element) {
      this.allTimeSlots[i].status = true;
    }
  });
}
```

Here's screen shot of time slots which displays `true` if the time slot is booked and false if available for debugging purpose.
[image]

When I run this code it doesn't throw any error but all the `div` elements created by `*ngFor` are disabled. I tried to use `*ngIf` instead of disabled, it works pretty well. But the problem is I want to display whether the time slot is available or not.

Comment: can you check if all the statuses of the time slots are true? (`console.log(this.allTimeSlots)` after the for loop), if they are then the issue is with how you are checking for a timeslot

Comment: i checked it, Even that {{item.status}} is for debugging purpose only. it prints the correct value true and false as i have given to it. but it doesn't work in [attr.disabled]

Comment: ok I have created a [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/W4JZVDoOaWzSAo3oQtDg?p=preview) demonstrating the problem you describe I'll try and see how to fix it now :)

Comment: Yes, Exactly same did happen to me, I have edited the question and added my screenshot in it, from which it can be better understood. @0mpurdy

Comment: You can try the syntax given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39347582/1009922).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Disabled cannot be used for a div element and only applied to the below elements

```
<button>    
<fieldset>  
<input> 
<keygen>    
<optgroup>  
<option>    
<select>    
<textarea>
```

[See this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp)

So for your issue, you can handle it by using:

```
<div 
  class="choice" 
  data-toggle="wizard-slot" 
  [class.disabled]="item.status" 
  (click)="slotSelected($event)">
  <input 
    type="radio" 
    name="slot" 
    value="{{item.timeSlot}}" 
    [disabled]="item.status">
  <span class="icon">{{item.timeSlot}}</span> {{item.status}}
</div>
```

and you should be adding styles

```
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. Giving error =>

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

Comment: should point out that this solution doesn't stop the click event from firing on that element as would normally be the case with the disabled attribute?

Comment: @Jacques if you want the click event not to fire add `pointer-events:none`

Answer (score 32):

**Use it this way:**

```
[attr.disabled]="isDisabled ? '' : null"
```

Same is for readonly.

Comment: If you have already logic with Reactive Forms, that will overwrite.

Comment: this is what I wanted. Angular is different

Comment: This is the correct and simplest solution.

Here's what I went with:   [attr.disabled]="isProcessing ? true: null"

Works in Angular 14.
Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

Use `[disabled]` instead of `[attr.disabled]`

This is because `[attr.disabled]="false"` will add `disabled="false"` to the element which in html, will still disable the element

### Syntax that will not disable an element

```html
<button>Not Disabled</button>
<button [disabled]="false">Not Disabled</button>
```

### Syntax that will disable an element

```html
<button disabled></button>
<button disabled="true"></button>
<button disabled="false"></button>
<button [attr.disabled]="true"></button>
<button [attr.disabled]="false"></button>
<button [disabled]="true"></button>
```

`disabled` will disable an element whether it is true or false, it's presence means that the element will be disabled. Angular will not add the `disabled` element at all for `[disabled]="variable"` if `variable` is false.

As you mentioned in your comment, you are using `div` elements and not buttons, which angular 2 doesn't recognise the disabled element of. I would recommend using a button if you are going to be capturing `click` events but if not you could do something like:

```html
<div [ngClass]="{ 'disabled': item.status }"></div>
```

and have a CSS class to show the time slot as booked.

More information on `[ngClass]` is available in [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: @user2136053 then you will surely like this as well: [attr.disabled]="isDisabled ? '' : null" (note the inner '' are 2 single quotes)

Comment: Late to the party, however i think [disabled]="false" does not disable the element. However [attr.disabled]="false" does.

Answer (score 4):

CSS

```
.disabled-contenct {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

HTML

```
<div [class.disabled-contenct]="!isDisabledContent"></div>
```

TS

```
isDisabledContent: boolean;
```

then you can toggle isDisabledContent any time.

Comment: This does not prevent keyboard interactions.

Answer (score 0):

As 0mpurdy answered, you should use [disabled] attribute. The variable doesn't have to be a boolean, but the expression should.

In your code, it determines if item.status is falsy or truthy. So if it's not null/NaN/undefined you will get "true" and the div will be disabled.

Instead insert an expression:

`[disabled]="item.status === 'occupied'"`

---

### Edit

Sorry I missed that.
Since you cannot disable a div put the disabled attribute inside the input tag.

```
<input type="radio" [disabled]="item.status === 'occupied'" name="slot" value="{{item.timeSlot}}">
```

since you want to display the selection as disabled, you'll need to put it directly inside the input. the radio button will be unclickable and a 'cursor: not-allowed' will show.

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried all these ways. but [disabled] doesn't works on div element.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! As of now i am using `div` element to do work of `radio` i need to disable that `div` only. The Answer which is approved above worked properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute directive will surely help you for disabling or enabling div or any other HTML element and it’s child elements.

**DisableDirective**

First, create an attribute directive that will take one parameter (appDisable)as input. It will disable/enable DOM elements and their child DOM elements based on the input.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

const DISABLED = 'disabled';
const APP_DISABLED = 'app-disabled';
const TAB_INDEX = 'tabindex';
const TAG_ANCHOR = 'a';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDisable]'
})
export class DisableDirective implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() appDisable = true;

  constructor(private eleRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.disableElement(this.eleRef.nativeElement);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.disableElement(this.eleRef.nativeElement);
  }

  private disableElement(element: any) {
    if (this.appDisable) {
      if (!element.hasAttribute(DISABLED)) {
        this.renderer.setAttribute(element, APP_DISABLED, '');
        this.renderer.setAttribute(element, DISABLED, 'true');

        // disabling anchor tab keyboard event
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === TAG_ANCHOR) {
          this.renderer.setAttribute(element, TAB_INDEX, '-1');
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (element.hasAttribute(APP_DISABLED)) {
        if (element.getAttribute('disabled') !== '') {
          element.removeAttribute(DISABLED);
        }
        element.removeAttribute(APP_DISABLED);
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === TAG_ANCHOR) {
          element.removeAttribute(TAB_INDEX);
        }
      }
    }
    if (element.children) {
      for (let ele of element.children) {
        this.disableElement(ele);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Do not forget to register DisableDirective in the AppModule

**How to use the directive in the component?** 
Pass the boolean value (true/false) in the directive from the component.

```
<div class="container" [appDisable]="true">
</div>
```

You can refer the complete Post [HERE](https://medium.com/@imdurgeshpal/enable-disable-all-dom-elements-inside-div-in-angular-using-directive-56ca4602ab7b)

Running example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4t5dkt?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html&view=preview)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can do it using [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#injecting-attribute-values). It is a simple method. See [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#injecting-attribute-values) on how to implement.