# How to make a link inside element with router link in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-material2

I need to make router link on a div element but also inside it add another anchor or button that opens menu. Because of router link menu cannot be opened. Clicking on a button fires router link. How can I make it work?

```
<div [routerLink]="/foo">
    <span>Title</span>
    <button (click)="openMenu()">Open menu</button>
</div>
```

Actually I am using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) and in fact the problem looks like this:

```
<md-card [routerLink]="/foo">
    <span>Title</span>

    <button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
      <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
    </button>

    <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item (click)="rename()">
        <md-icon>create</md-icon>
        <span>Rename</span>
      </button>
      <button md-menu-item (click)="share()">
        <md-icon>share</md-icon>
        <span>Share</span>
      </button>
    </md-menu>
</md-card>
```

Comment: Did you try the solution I added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below,

```
<button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)="open($event)" >
  <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
</button>
```

in corresponding ts file,

```
open(e){
  // this will stop event to propagate to work on link click.
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you, I simplified your code to `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` and it works. I have found very similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-event-propagation-in-angular-2