# Angular Material / Routing - sidenav selection causes page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Currently I'm developing an Angular Web-App using Angular Material. The sidenav works flawlessly but causes a full page refresh every time I open a new router link.

HTML:

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/page1" (click)="sidenav.close()">page1</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/page2" (click)="sidenav.close()">page2</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

app.module.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'page1', component: Page1Component},
{ path: 'page2', component: Page2Component},
];
```

Is there any possibility to deactivate the page refresh?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-mouse-event-propagation-in-angular) SO question and the answers given.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
(click)="sidenav.close()"
```

with

```
(click)="drawer.toggle()"
```

has solved the problem.