# A way to assign click event to internal button inside a wrapper component Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a wrapper component for buttons which looks something like

```
<button [id]="fn()" (click)="this.click.emit()"></button>
```

I am using the selector to

```
 <btn-generic>
```

and applying a separate click event to it ,but the click gets applied on the wrapper component as well,Is there a way to pass the click event on the button alone.

Comment: You'll need to add some code to your question to demonstrate what you're doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Stop mouse event propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-mouse-event-propagation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop mouse event propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-mouse-event-propagation)

Comment: `[id]="fn()" (click)="this.click.emit()"` <= neither of those assignments make any sense.  If you want help you need to provide an [mcve], I recommend creating one using https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `$event.stopPropagation()` to the `(click)` event from the button.

Like this `<button (click)="doSomething(); $event.stopPropagation()">click me!</button>`

Comment: Tried it ,it doesn't work.If I use the selector btn-generic on other components ,the (click) event is applied to the enitre wrapper component.I am unable to catch the event and stop it from propogation