# Nested mat-select in mat-checkbox mischief

Tags: angular, angular-material2

A mat-select inside a mat-checkbox label is tricky: if I click the mat-select, the checkbox is also toggled. I don't want this to happen...

I have tried taking the select out of the checkbox, but then it is hard to display the two nicely on one line.
I have also replace the mat-select with a select. This works, but is less perfect. (e.g., if I want to do multiple selections).

Here is a working example: https://angular-7em9xn.stackblitz.io

with code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7em9xn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop mouse event propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-mouse-event-propagation)

Answer (score 0):

Add a directive (click-stop-propagation.directive.ts)

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickStopPropagation]',
})
export class ClickStopPropagationDirective {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: any): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

And use it on mat-select

```
<mat-checkbox>Check this out! 
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]='when' appClickStopPropagation>
    <mat-option value="now">now</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="later">later</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-checkbox>
```

While `event.stopPropagation();` should be enough for some reason it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to implement your suggestion here: https://angular-7em9xn-fxehqr.stackblitz.io but it still doesn't behave.