# How to make routerlink both clickable and double-clickable in Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Similar question has been asked multiple times but I cannot get this to work. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-mouse-event-propagation) is some answers that don't work for most people. This **might not** be angular issue per se, but I'm trying to solve this in ng app.

I want link to work normal when clicked. In addition i want the item that contains the link to be doubleclickable to open the link to split-area on side of router-outlet. So in my navigation-menu I have:

```
    <li *ngIf="propertiesTabVisible"  class="nav-item tab-nav-item"
      [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' [routerLinkActiveOptions]='{ exact: true }' 
      (dblclick)="toggleTab('/properties/' + sessionId)">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/properties", sessionId]'
       [class.disabled]="(propertiesLinkDisabled | async)"
       (click)="navigateWithDelay('/properties/' +sessionId)">
        <mat-icon class="tab-nav-item-icon">assignment</mat-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
```

and in component.ts:

```
  private block = true;
  private isCancelled = false;

  private delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  private async sleepExample(url: string) {
    await this.delay(200);
    if (!this.block) {
      this.router.navigate([url]);
    }
  }

  navigateWithDelay(url: string) :boolean {
    this.block = true;
    this.isCancelled = false;
    this.sleepExample(url).then(() => {
      if (!this.isCancelled) {
        this.block = false;
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

  toggleTab(url: string) {
    this.isCancelled = true;
    toggleTabVisibility(url);
  }
```

However this does not work. Even though both handlers are called and they function as I expected on top of that router outlet works so the navigation happens. How to prevent link click propagation in click-hanlder?

Comment: Can't you call `$event.stopPropagation()`? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-mouse-event-propagation)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I didn't get that to work. Maybe my syntax was wrong or something.

Comment: oh, actually i didn't. I have to try this directive approach.

Comment: It's not an Angular issue, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event

Comment: As I wrote in the question both click and dblclick handlers are called so not that question @Mehdi . I need single click to react to my single click event AND NOT default behavior which is navigate the link

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha: This is very much Angular related. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21457.

Comment: Then don’t put routerLink and handle your routing in the component.ts

Comment: I already solved this. Will write answer when I know best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason $event.stopPropagation() and ;$event.preventDefault() are not working in routerLink is described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21457).

Here is working example where click event is moved in mat-icon inside anchor and handler calls both:

```
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $event.preventDefault();
```

.html:

```
<li *ngIf="propertiesTabVisible"  class="nav-item tab-nav-item" [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' [routerLinkActiveOptions]='{ exact: true }'
(dblclick)="toggleTab('/properties/' +sessionId)">
  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/properties", sessionId]' [class.disabled]="(propertiesLinkDisabled | async)">
    <mat-icon class="tab-nav-item-icon" (click)="navigateWithDelay($event, '/properties/' +sessionId)">assignment</mat-icon>
  </a>
</li>
```

.ts:

```
  toggleTab(url: string) {
    this.isCancelled = true;
    this.ngRedux.dispatch(this.actions.toggleWindowUrl({
      windowId: this.tabService.windowId,
      url: url,
      isSplit: true
    }));
  }

  private isCancelled = false;

  private delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  private async waitForDoubleClick() {
    await this.delay(200);
  }

  navigateWithDelay($event: any, url: string) {
    this.isCancelled = false;
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.waitForDoubleClick().then(() => {
      if (!this.isCancelled) {
        this.router.navigate([url]);
      }
    });
  }
```