# Disable button event when embedded mat icon is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, google-material-icons

I am having a mat-icon inside a button. Button is having an event defined and mat-icon is having another event defined. When I click on mat-icon, its event is fired along with button event as mat-icon is inside button tag. I don't want button event to be fired when mat-icon is clicked and don't want mat-icon to be fired when button is clicked excluding the mat-icon part in the UI. Here is a snippet of HTML in angular framework.

```
<button type="button" class="" (click)="someevent">
            <span >
              Text
            </span>
            <mat-icon  class='' (click)="differentevent">
                       delete
            </mat-icon>
</button>
```

How to resolve this? I am using Angular and click events are defined in typescript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop mouse event propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-mouse-event-propagation)

Comment: No. I have edited the question, for more clarification.

Comment: Have you tried as suggested in the above answer?

Comment: `<mat-icon (click)="event$.stopPropagation(); differentevent">`

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rt6wbx

Comment: @Reactgular it must be: `$event.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$event.stopPropagation()`:

> The `event.stopPropagation()` method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

Just replace mat-icon markup with:

```
<mat-icon (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); differentevent()">delete</mat-icon>
```

So when you click on delete icon it stops the event bubbling hence your parent click event will not called and then it calls the next method.

The order of `stopPropagation()` is not important - you can also use it as:

```
<mat-icon (click)="differentevent(); $event.stopPropagation()">delete</mat-icon>
```

[`Online_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rt6wbx)

Comment: While this is working fine, I get in browser console - Cannot read property ‘stopPropagation’ of undefined. This breaks the functionality of my mat-icon. Also in terminal it displays set max event listeners. Some leaking is happening.

Comment: Also I am getting Error- Uncaught (in promise)

Comment: @RaghavGupta this might be cause of type check component.ts for this

Comment: Ok I commented stopPropagation in ts file as you did and only kept it in HTML. This resolves everything.