# How to prevent event bubbling in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, event-propagation

Please understand, I'm new in Angular and developing overall so this might be a very unexperienced problem.

The problem is that I am calling a function from a component's HTML template file with $event as an argument and it ends up capturing a different element from the one I wished to target. That exact element I am calling the event on has two children...

HTML:

```
          <div class="cursorPointer" (click)="answeredQuestion($event)">
                <div id="chickenTenders" class="backImageCov question_0Img"></div>
                <h3 class="questionSubTitle">Chicken Tenders</h3>
           </div>
```

I am aiming to retrieve the div container with **`"cursorPointer"`** every single time I call this event. I hypothesize that it's an event bubbling problem because if I were to click on the div container with the id of `"chickenTenders"`, that same container will be returned by the `$event` argument in the `answeredQuestion()`  function on my ts file...

I have already searched online ([Stop mouse event propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-mouse-event-propagation)) but in this example the student is asking a question that came from a directive so I got confused as to what the solution could be...

I have already tried:

```
(click)="answeredQuestion(0, $event);false"
```

And:

```
(click)="answeredQuestion(0, $event); $event.stopPropagation()"
```

However, none seem to help the cause. Putting it simply, I hope the solution would give me a simple way to get access to that parent element (`<div class="cursorPointer">`) every single time, even if the child elements are the ones clicked.

Thank you for your time guys, I appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you first have a call of `answeredQuestion` with one argument, and then with two?

Comment: Well,  it has barely to do with the whole point of the question. However, it was an editing error in stack overflow. I had to edit my code a lot more in order to simplify it and make the main question a whole lot more understandable. There where unnecessary bits of code. Think of it as if it only had one parameter originally... ($event reference.) Thank you for your comment BTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you disabled the pointer events for the child elements with CSS?

```
.cursorPointer > div, .cursorPointer > h3{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or better:

```
.cursorPointer > * {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can handle the event propagation(bubbling) in angular.

Use this in your child component.

```
onClick(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // do your stuff
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) to grab a reference to your desired element.

```html
<div #clickElement class="cursorPointer" (click)="answeredQuestion(clickElement)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to access `currentTarget`:

```
answeredQuestion($event){
    const cursorPointer = $event.currentTarget
    // etc.
}
```

This gives you the element where the handler is attached. `$event.target` gives you the element where the click occurred, in this case on of the children.